# Why is my svg chart not rendering properly for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I built an SVG bar chart that seems to work fine in every browser but IE. My ticks,labels, bars etc. are not rendering in IE. Only the axis lines are rendering.

After a preliminary IE + SVG search, I tried adding a viewbox attribute to the chart, but this did not change anything. It still rendered the same undesirable way. No errors in the IE console for me that I could see. What am I missing?

I'd share some code, but it's probably better to just copy/paste the code here into a place that supports viewing with IE: https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/QWWarrp

```
<svg id="hourly-chart" height="285">
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">
    <g class="y axis" id="y-axis-ticks">
      <line class="y-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="y-axis-zero-line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="240"></line>
    </g>
    <g id="hourly-chart-bars"></g>
    <g class="x axis" id="hourly-x-ticks" transform="translate(0,0)">
      <line class="x-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="x-axis-zero-line" x1="0" y1="240" x2="600" y2="240"></line>
    </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Expected result is the same chart on chrome and IE. Actual result is the proper chart in chrome, but a blank chart with only axis lines drawn in IE.

Actual result:
[image: actualresult]

Expected result:
[image: expectedresult]

Any help?

Comment: codepen doesn't work with IE11 - so, a pointless link

Comment: I see your code uses `const`, `let`, `...` and god knows what other ES2015+ syntax that IE11 can not possibly begin to comprehend

Comment: I guess you didn't see the errors in the browser developer tools console when you tried to inflict this code on IE11

Comment: where's the rest of your [mcve] HTML? Are you declaring `<!doctype html>` to make sure the document is parsed as HTML5, which is the only version of HTML in which the `<svg>` element is a legal element?

Comment: Believe its a problem with building the SVG with strings and innerHTML. createElementNS() seems to be the way to go to have it work with IE (for future people who may discover this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related that Internet Explorer doesn't currently support the innerHTML property on SVG Elements. So, the new nodes was not append to the SVG element. You could using the console.log() method to check the value.

To solve this issue, we could use the createElementNS() method to create an SVG node element, then using the document.appendChild() method to add the new node in the SVG element.

```
    //add <g> node
    var newg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    newg.setAttribute('class', 'tick');
    newg.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 60 * j) + ')');

    //add <line> node
    var newLine3 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine3.setAttribute('class', 'gray');
    newLine3.setAttribute('x1', '0');
    newLine3.setAttribute('y1', '0');
    newLine3.setAttribute('x2', '-30');
    newLine3.setAttribute('y2', '0');
    newg.appendChild(newLine3);

    var newLine4 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine4.setAttribute('class', 'gray');
    newLine4.setAttribute('x1', '0');
    newLine4.setAttribute('y1', '0');
    newLine4.setAttribute('x2', width);
    newLine4.setAttribute('y2', '0');
    newg.appendChild(newLine4);

    //add <text> node
    var newtext = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
    newtext.setAttribute('class', 'y-tick');
    newtext.setAttribute('dy', '.32em');
    newtext.setAttribute('x', '-9');
    newtext.setAttribute('y', '-30');
    newtext.setAttribute('style', 'text-anchor: end;');
    newtext.textContent = ticks[j];
    newg.appendChild(newtext);

    //using appendChild method to add child node.
    tickContainer.appendChild(newg);
```

The detail sample code as below:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="hourly-chart-wrapper">
    <svg id="hourly-chart" height="285" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g transform="translate(40,40)">
            <g class="y axis" id="y-axis-ticks">
                <line class="y-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="y-axis-zero-line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="240"></line>
            </g>
            <g id="hourly-chart-bars"></g>
            <g class="x axis" id="hourly-x-ticks" transform="translate(0,0)">
                <line class="x-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="x-axis-zero-line" x1="0" y1="240" x2="600" y2="240"></line>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<script>
    var index = 0;
    // Total bar container width 35 px
    // Labels before formatting
    var labels = [['Wed', '11 PM'], ['Thu', '12 AM'], ['Thu', '1 AM'], ['Thu', '2 AM'], ['Thu', '3 AM'], ['Thu', '4 AM'], ['Thu', '5 AM'], ['Thu', '6 AM'], ['Thu', '7 AM'], ['Thu', '8 AM'], ['Thu', '9 AM'], ['Thu', '10 AM'], ['Thu', '11 AM'], ['Thu', '12 PM'], ['Thu', '1 PM'], ['Thu', '2 PM'], ['Thu', '3 PM'], ['Thu', '4 PM'], ['Thu', '5 PM'], ['Thu', '6 PM'], ['Thu', '7 PM'], ['Thu', '8 PM'], ['Thu', '9 PM'], ['Thu', '10 PM'], ['Thu', '11 PM'], ['Fri', '12 AM'], ['Fri', '1 AM'], ['Fri', '2 AM'], ['Fri', '3 AM']]; // Data points

    var data = [0.25, 0.56, 0.5, 0.5, 0.86, 0.45, 0.3, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 0.6, 0.4]; // Get max value from data set

    var maxDataValue = Math.max.apply(Math, data); // Max Y Tick

    var maxYValue = yAxisRangeImperial(maxDataValue); // Get chart svg

    var hourlyChart = document.getElementById('hourly-chart'); // Get y axis ticks g

    var tickContainer = document.getElementById('y-axis-ticks'); // Get y axis zero line

    var yAxisZeroLine = document.getElementById('y-axis-zero-line'); // Get x axis zero line

    var xAxisZeroLine = document.getElementById('x-axis-zero-line'); // Get chart ticks by id

    var hourlyChartXTicks = document.getElementById('hourly-x-ticks'); // Get chart bar group by id

    var hourlyChartBars = document.getElementById('hourly-chart-bars'); // Function to determine chart width

    function chartWidth(data) {
        var width = 600;
        var possibleWidth = data.length * 35;

        if (possibleWidth > 600) {
            width = possibleWidth;
        }

        return width;
    } // Function to figure out max Y Tick


    function yAxisRangeImperial(max) {
        if (max < 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (max < 2) {
            return 2;
        } else if (max < 4) {
            return 4;
        } else if (max < 8) {
            return 8;
        } else if (max < 12) {
            return 12;
        } else if (max < 24) {
            return 24;
        } else if (max < 48) {
            return 48;
        } else if (max < 72) {
            return 72;
        } else if (max < 96) {
            return 96;
        } else {
            return 192;
        }
    }

    ; // Function to populate the y axis ticks and depth labels

    function populateHourlyYAxisLabels(max, unit) {
        var interval = max / 4;
        var ticks = [interval + unit, interval * 2 + unit, interval * 3 + unit, interval * 4 + unit];
        var width = chartWidth(data);
        var height = 240;

        //tickContainer.appendChild('<line class="gray" x2="-30" y2="0"></line><line class="gray" x1="0" x2="' + width + '" y2="0"></line>');

        var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        newLine.setAttribute('class', 'gray');
        newLine.setAttribute('x1', '0');
        newLine.setAttribute('y1', '0');
        newLine.setAttribute('x2', '-30');
        newLine.setAttribute('y2', '0');
        tickContainer.appendChild(newLine);

        var newLine2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        newLine2.setAttribute('class', 'gray');
        newLine2.setAttribute('x1', '0');
        newLine2.setAttribute('y1', '0');
        newLine2.setAttribute('x2', width);
        newLine2.setAttribute('y2', '0');
        tickContainer.appendChild(newLine2);

        xAxisZeroLine.setAttribute("x2", width);

        for (var j = ticks.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (j !== 0) {
                //tickContainer.innerHTML += '<g class="tick" transform="translate(0,' + (height - 60 * j) + ')"><line class="gray" x2="-30" y2="0"></line>
                //<line class="gray" x1="0" x2="' + width + '" y2="0"></line>
                //<text class="y-tick" dy=".32em" x="-9" y="-30" style="text-anchor: end;">' + ticks[j] + '</text></g > ';
                var newg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
                newg.setAttribute('class', 'tick');
                newg.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 60 * j) + ')');

                var newLine3 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
                newLine3.setAttribute('class', 'gray');
                newLine3.setAttribute('x1', '0');
                newLine3.setAttribute('y1', '0');
                newLine3.setAttribute('x2', '-30');
                newLine3.setAttribute('y2', '0');
                newg.appendChild(newLine3);

                var newLine4 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
                newLine4.setAttribute('class', 'gray');
                newLine4.setAttribute('x1', '0');
                newLine4.setAttribute('y1', '0');
                newLine4.setAttribute('x2', width);
                newLine4.setAttribute('y2', '0');
                newg.appendChild(newLine4);

                var newtext = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                newtext.setAttribute('class', 'y-tick');
                newtext.setAttribute('dy', '.32em');
                newtext.setAttribute('x', '-9');
                newtext.setAttribute('y', '-30');
                newtext.setAttribute('style', 'text-anchor: end;');
                newtext.textContent = ticks[j];
                newg.appendChild(newtext);

                tickContainer.appendChild(newg);

            } else {
                //tickContainer.innerHTML += '<g class="tick" transform="translate(0,' + height + ')">
                //<line x2="-30" y2="0"></line>
                //<text dy=".32em" x="-9" y="-30" style="text-anchor: end;">' + ticks[j] + '</text></g > ';

                var newg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
                newg.setAttribute('class', 'tick');
                newg.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 60 * j) + ')');

                var newLine3 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
                newLine3.setAttribute('class', 'gray');
                newLine3.setAttribute('x1', '0');
                newLine3.setAttribute('y1', '0');
                newLine3.setAttribute('x2', '-30');
                newLine3.setAttribute('y2', '0');
                newg.appendChild(newLine3);

                var newtext = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                newtext.setAttribute('dy', '.32em');
                newtext.setAttribute('x', '-9');
                newtext.setAttribute('y', '-30');
                newtext.setAttribute('style', 'text-anchor: end;');
                newtext.textContent = ticks[j];
                newg.appendChild(newtext);

                tickContainer.appendChild(newg);
            }
        };
    }; // Function to determine hour display interval

    function hoursLabelInterval(hours) {
        if (hours <= 6) {
            return 1;
        } else if (hours <= 12) {
            return 2;
        } else if (hours <= 24) {
            return 4;
        } else if (hours <= 36) {
            return 6;
        } else if (hours <= 48) {
            return 8;
        } else if (hours <= 60) {
            return 10;
        } else if (hours <= 72) {
            return 12;
        } else {
            return 24;
        }
    } // Function to create x axis labels

    function createLabels(labels) {
        var hoursInterval = hoursLabelInterval(labels.length);
        var currentDay = '';
        var formattedLabels = labels.map(function (label, i) {
            if (i % hoursInterval === 0) {
                if (label[0] !== currentDay) {
                    currentDay = label[0];
                    return [label[0], label[1]];
                }
                return ['', label[1]];
            }
            return ['', ''];
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < formattedLabels.length; i++) {
            var translateDistance = void 0;

            if (i === 0) {
                translateDistance = 15;
            } else {
                translateDistance = i * 30 + 15;
            }
            if (formattedLabels[i][1].length && i !== 0) {
                //hourlyChartXTicks.innerHTML += '
                //<g class="tick" transform="translate(' + translateDistance + ',0)">
                //<line class="y-axis-zero-line axis-line dash gray" stroke-dasharray="4" stroke-width="1" x1="-13" y1="0" x2="-13" y2="240"></line>
                //<text class="label-day" dy=".71em" y="-20" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][0] + '</text>
                //<text class="label-time" dy=".71em" y="-10" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][1] + '</text></g > ';
                var newg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
                newg.setAttribute('class', 'tick');
                newg.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + translateDistance + ',0)');

                var newLine3 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
                newLine3.setAttribute('class', 'y-axis-zero-line axis-line dash gray');
                newLine3.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', '4');
                newLine3.setAttribute('stroke-width', '1');
                newLine3.setAttribute('x1', '-13');
                newLine3.setAttribute('y1', '0');
                newLine3.setAttribute('x2', '-13');
                newLine3.setAttribute('y2', '240');
                newg.appendChild(newLine3);

                var newtext = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                newtext.setAttribute('class', 'label-day');
                newtext.setAttribute('dy', '.71em');
                newtext.setAttribute('x', '0');
                newtext.setAttribute('y', '-20');
                newtext.textContent = formattedLabels[i][0];
                newg.appendChild(newtext);

                var newtext = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                newtext.setAttribute('class', 'label-time');
                newtext.setAttribute('dy', '.71em');
                newtext.setAttribute('x', '0');
                newtext.setAttribute('y', '-10');
                newtext.textContent = formattedLabels[i][1];
                newg.appendChild(newtext);

                hourlyChartXTicks.appendChild(newg);

            } else {
                // hourlyChartXTicks.innerHTML += '
                //<g class="tick" transform="translate(' + translateDistance + ',0)">
                //<text class="label-day" dy=".71em" y="-20" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][0] + '</text>
                //<text class="label-time" dy=".71em" y="-10" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][1] + '</text></g > ';

                var newg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
                newg.setAttribute('class', 'tick');
                newg.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + translateDistance + ',0)');

                var newtext = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                newtext.setAttribute('class', 'label-day');
                newtext.setAttribute('dy', '.71em');
                newtext.setAttribute('x', '0');
                newtext.setAttribute('y', '-20');
                newtext.textContent = formattedLabels[i][0];
                newg.appendChild(newtext);

                var newtext = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                newtext.setAttribute('class', 'label-time');
                newtext.setAttribute('dy', '.71em');
                newtext.setAttribute('x', '0');
                newtext.setAttribute('y', '-10');
                newtext.textContent = formattedLabels[i][1];
                newg.appendChild(newtext);

                hourlyChartXTicks.appendChild(newg);
            }
        }
    } // Function to compute bar height


    function barHeight(maxChartYTick, individualBarAccumulation) {
        var barHeightDecimalPercentage = individualBarAccumulation / maxChartYTick;
        return barHeightDecimalPercentage;
    } // Function to create bars


    function createBars(data, maxYTick) {
        for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
            var translateDistance = void 0;

            if (k === 0) {
                translateDistance = 5;
            } else {
                translateDistance = 5 + k * 30;
            }

            var height = barHeight(maxYTick, data[k]);
            //hourlyChartBars.innerHTML += '<rect class="bar" x="' + translateDistance + '" width="25" y="' + (240 - 240 * height) + '" height="' + 240 * height + '"></rect>';

            var newrect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
            newrect.setAttribute('class', 'bar');
            newrect.setAttribute('x', translateDistance);
            newrect.setAttribute('width', '25');
            newrect.setAttribute('y', (240 - 240 * height));
            newrect.setAttribute('height', (240 * height));

            hourlyChartBars.appendChild(newrect);
            console.log((index++) + ": " + hourlyChartBars.innerHTML);
        }
    }

    hourlyChart.setAttribute("width", chartWidth(data));
    populateHourlyYAxisLabels(maxYValue, '"');
    createLabels(labels);
    createBars(data, maxYValue);
</script>
```

The result in IE browser:

[image]